# Java JUnit 5 AssertAll Stream

Tags: java, junit, java-stream, junit5

I'm having

```
ArrayList<Executable>( () -> assertTrue(true), ... )
```

now I'm trying to convert it into an `Stream<Executable>` to use assertAll Method.

```
  public static void assertAll(Stream<Executable> executables)
                                                   throws MultipleFailuresError
```

How can I convert a `ArrayList<Executable>`(if there is no cleaner way than ArrayList) into a `Stream<Executable>`?

Reference: http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertAll-org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable...-

Answer (score 4):

Just call the [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) method which is inherited by all classes implementing `Collection`:

```
assertAll(executableList.stream());
```

Note that if you already have the elements of the `ArrayList` readily available, you can already pass them to `assertAll`, as there is an [overloaded method](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertAll-org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable...-) that takes varargs input:

```
assertAll(() -> assertTrue(true), ...)
```

This way there is no need to create an `ArrayList` or `Stream`.

Comment: The point in that is I want Go create testsuites dynamically, so if one of it fails, the Test failed, in the arraylist is the Suite stored, still possible?

Comment: I did not fully understand your question, but if the assertions are created dynamically, and you need to use `assertAll` then you can convert the list to a stream as I mentioned in the answer. If there is something I'm missing, maybe it's better to re-formulate your original question.